# Solana metaplex-program-library thread 'main' panicked at 'Code not parseable: Error("space must be provided with init")'

Tags: solana, metaplex, anchor-solana

I am trying to compile and set up a local Solana node with Metaplex installed for local development. Right now when compiling with **anchor build** - I've been getting the following error:

```
To deploy this program:
  $ solana program deploy /sol/metaplex/program-library/target/deploy/mpl_fixed_price_sale.so
The program address will default to this keypair (override with --program-id):
  /sol/metaplex/program-library/target/deploy/mpl_fixed_price_sale-keypair.json
thread 'main' panicked at 'Code not parseable: Error("space must be provided with init")', lang/syn/src/idl/file.rs:360:58
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/result.rs:1749:5
   3: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnMut<A> for &mut F>::call_mut
   4: anchor_syn::idl::file::parse_account_derives
   5: anchor_syn::idl::file::parse
   6: anchor_cli::extract_idl
   7: anchor_cli::build_cwd
   8: anchor_cli::build_all
   9: anchor_cli::build
  10: anchor_cli::entry
  11: anchor::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

It appears to originate in: **fixed-price-sale/program/src/lib.rs** inside `pub struct Buy` the following lines:

```
pub struct Buy<'info> {
...
  #[account(init_if_needed, seeds=[HISTORY_PREFIX.as_bytes(), user_wallet.key().as_ref(), market.key().as_ref()], bump, payer=user_wallet)]
  trade_history: Box<Account<'info, TradeHistory>>,
...
}
```

When I comment these two lines out and comment out an entire **fixed-price-sale/program/src/processor/buy.rs** - it compiles with some warnings, but clearly there is now functionality missing. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. The **space** parameter is missing.

Need to change:

```
...
#[account(
  init_if_needed, 
  seeds=[
    HISTORY_PREFIX.as_bytes(), 
    user_wallet.key().as_ref(), 
    market.key().as_ref()
  ], 
  bump, 
  payer=user_wallet
)]
trade_history: Box<Account<'info, TradeHistory>>,
...
```

to this:

```
...
#[account(
  init_if_needed, 
  space=TradeHistory::LEN, // <-------------- Added this line
  seeds=[
    HISTORY_PREFIX.as_bytes(), 
    user_wallet.key().as_ref(), 
    market.key().as_ref()
  ], 
  bump,
  payer=user_wallet
)]
trade_history: Box<Account<'info, TradeHistory>>,
...
```